# What's the difference of the return of “require” and the actual object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

In node.js, we usually use "require" to include the module of other files, no matter its from ourselves or third parties. However, it is ambiguous for me the difference between the return "item" and an real object.

In my point of view, the return "item" hasn't been initiated yet, so it supposes not an object. However, sometime we can use the method under it directly.

How should I realize this difference?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The return value can be anything (number, string, object, function, etc.), but it's usually an object. Could you elaborate on why you think "return value from `require`" and "object" are mutually exclusive? In particular I don't understand what you mean by "*...the return "item" hasn't been initiated yet, so it supposes not an object.*"

Comment: `require` is a function (not a keyword for import namespace like java or c#), `require` function can return everything, you can write a simple module to know more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I clarify myself more now. My point here is the difference between function and object in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

When you require a file/module the **code in the required file is executed** and its exports object returned to you. For example in the following code:

```
// util.js
var plusOne = function(x) { return x + 1; }
exports.plusOne = plusOne;

// app.js
var util = require('./util.js');
var z = util.plusOne(1);
console.log(z); // will output 2
```

when you execute `app.js`, `app.js` will require `util.js`. When the `require('./util.js')` line is reached it executes the code in util.js and returns to you it exports object. In this case the exports object contains the definition of a function (plusOne) but it could contain a more complex object.

This is why you get an object already initialized.

Something to keep in mind though, is that the code in the require will be executed only the first time you require the file. After that, the object already initialized will be returned to you. For example, if you were to require('./util.js') in another files, Node is smart enough to realize that it has already executed this file and gives you back the object that it produced (in this case an object with a function inside of it) without having to re-execute the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though I think I asked the wrong questions. I still think you provide useful information in the later part. Thanks again!